# Passing a list of grouping variables to an R function

Tags: r

I have come up with the following function in doing a few calculations on a data set. I pass the dataframe, grouping variable and the subject name into the function.

```
f1 <- function(df, group = "country", subject = "Math") {
   df %>%
    group_by(!! rlang::ensym(group)) %>% 
    summarise(ci = list(bootstrap_ci(sex, !! rlang::ensym(subject), weight))) %>% 
    unnest_wider(ci) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(grouped_by = fct_reorder(!! rlang::ensym(group), avg),
           subject = subject)
}
```

However I now want to group by multiple columns in a few cases. In that case I'd like to reuse the above function. But am not sure how to do this.

I tried passing the list of grouping variables as a list c("var1", "var2"), which didn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Without changing much of your function a simple fix would be to use `group_by_at` which will accept string column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(df, group = "country", subject = "Math") {
      df %>%
       group_by_at(group) %>% 
       summarise(ci = list(bootstrap_ci(sex, !!ensym(subject), weight))) %>% 
       unnest_wider(ci) %>% 
       ungroup() %>% 
       mutate(grouped_by = fct_reorder(!!ensym(group), avg),
              subject = subject)
}
```

So if `f1(df)` works with default parameters, for multiple groups

```
f1(df, c('group1', 'group2'))
```

should also work.

Comment: The group_by seems to work however, the fct_reorder() gives an error when multiple values are used

Comment: I don't know how `fct_reorder` works but what is it suppose to do? If not in function how will you use it outside function when passing two variables? Probably using `ensyms` might help. So try with `!!!ensyms(group)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update.  You now want to use `across()` with `group_by()` instead of `group_by_at()`.

Example: `group_by(across(variables))`